# Scheduler, is it too heavy?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a Scheduled Tasks that is too heavy, so my question is, a too heavy Scheduled Tasks could drop down the coldfusion server? i mean sometimes my Scheduled Tasks exceeded the loop limit time, anyway I am looking for other way to make the same thing but no too heavy.

Comment: Maybe if you show us the code from the 'heavy' scheduled task(s) we could suggest improvements?

Comment: The answer to your specific question is "yes".  Any task can bring down the server if it consumes too many resources.  It doesn't matter how it's called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a scheduled task is really just an automatic call for a normal CF page request. This means, if you manually bring up the scheduled task URL in a browser window, does it time out there as well?

Remember that a scheduled task is being called and run by the server which will mean you can have different session, CGI, request and form scope values as opposed to an actual user. However, you can use the requestTimeout attribute of the [CFSETTING tag](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d68.html) to extend how long the page will have to complete the tasks before it times out. The requestTimeout attribute takes a value which represents number of seconds after which, if no request back from the server, CF considers the page to be unresponsive.

However, it would depend greatly upon what your scheduled task is actually doing. There are all kinds of ways you could take code to break it into constituent parts for quicker processing. Maybe figuring out what the loop is doing (and does it really need to do all of everything it's doing) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things to consider.

Firstly, your task takes a while to run, and currently times out. There's some things to investigate here:

1. well not an investigation, but you can set the `requesttimeout` for that request via `<cfsetting>` as per @coldfusiondevshop's suggestion.
2. You could audit your code to see if it can be coded differently to not take so long to run. Due to the nature of work that's generally done as a task, this might not be possible.
3. Depending on your ColdFusion version (pls always tag your questions with the CF version, as well as just "ColdFusion") you could leverage the enhanced scheduling CF10 has to split the  tasks into smaller chunks and chain them together, thus making the parts of the sum less likely to time out. This too is not always possible, but is a consideration.

The other thing to think about is whether it might be worth having a separate CF instance running for your tasks. As well as your task timing out, it could also be slowing down processing for everyone else too, whilst that's running. Have you checked that? For a single task this is probably overkill, but it's good to bear in mind that tasks don't *need* to be run by the same CF instance(s) as the rest of the site, and indeed there's a compelling case not to do so if there are a lot of tasks that will strain a CF instance's resources.

In summary: increase your timeout via `<cfsetting>`, then audit your code to see if you can improve its performance. The other things I say are just "bonus point" suggestions.